# Gradle: How to run test with status each line?

Tags: gradle

When I run gradle test, it output as following:

```
:test
> Building 80% > :test > 86 tests completed
```

and it rewrite the line `> Building 80% > :test > 86 tests completed` as it's progressing forward.

What I want is to prevent gradle from replacing this line and make it output line by line, for example:

```
:test
:test > 86 tests completed
:test > 87 tests completed
:test > 88 tests completed
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the `test` block

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

test {
    // show standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s) on the console, without this
    // the text output printed by the tests won't show.
    // ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    def testCount = 0
    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        // descriptor is of type TestDescriptor, result is of type TestResult
        // ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestDescriptor.html
        // ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestResult.html
        logger.lifecycle("Test {count: ${++testCount} name: $descriptor.name result: $result.resultType}")
    }
}
```

Then you will see your output during the test task.  Of course you could us another logging level depending on what you want but `info`, `debug`, `error` are also available.  The `lifecycle` will always show, unless `-q` command line arg is passed.

```
$ ./gradlew clean test
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
Test {count: 1 name: testSomeLibraryMethod result: SUCCESS}

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.229 secs
```